# How to elegantly clear data when switching between two nextjs dynamic routing pages?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have some dynamic routing pages, Eg: pageA,pageB. They are use the same file like: '[id].js'.

When I change the route from pageA to pageB, the data in pageA are not been cleared.These data still exist.So I stupidly cleared the data in useEffect, just like clearing the data of the Modal component.

How can I clear this data elegantly. Just like edit some config to make the change like changing between different pages.

Comment: Why are pageA and pageB the same component instance? how does that happen?

Comment: I set `[id].js` as a template. An id is a page.In the file I display different page according to different id and he different back-end data.

Comment: In next, I can change the route without refresh the page. When I use two Dynamic routing Pages And Switch between them, this problem happened.

Comment: what do you mean by data in  pageA are not been cleared?

Comment: files like: pages/test/[id].js.
And use two pages: test/A test/B
next version: 9.5
You can try it..

Comment: I don't know how it happend. But I find it....

Comment: You'll have to provide some code for us to tell why the data isn't being updated correctly.